# получение reactions в slack

Tags: java, slack

Как получить reactions в Slack зная его timeStamp?
Используя Java.
У меня бот видит новые сообщения и всю информацию об сообщении, но обратиться к старому сообщению зная его timeStamp не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается так:

```
       Map<String, String> params = createParams(timestamp);
        return session.postGenericSlackCommand(params, "reactions.get");
```